# Get json data from a php file

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

Good morning folks,

I'm just that beginner in json, I have a formated data (array) encoded and sent from a php file, the only thing I want is how to get this data and alert it to be simple??

My object sent from the php file is like:
`{"stat":"opened","do":"close"}`
I found the best way to do so, `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(???)`but really can't get it work and Google does not want to help me this time !!

Edit: The json object received from a post response:`$.post("page.php",{},function(data){/*Here I should pars data and act with*/});`

Very glad if you support me in this issue!
Regards.

Comment: Could you provide more of the Javascript you are using so we can see how it's retrieving the PHP file in question and where it's failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have jQuery, you just pass the JSON string to that `$.parseJSON()`. The return value is the native object.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"stat":"opened","do":"close"}');
console.log(obj.stat, obj.do);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, you been always on my topics, in fact, I obtained data from a post response: `$.post("file.php",{},function(data){/*Here I should pars the json object to act with*/});`

Comment: but the problem is not solved yet, I just provided pore details about the way I received data.

Comment: @dany90 Try it on the `data` variable.

Comment: Wow, God how close was I, thank you Alex, you inspired me again, the solution was `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           alert(obj.stat);` really as said, the solution is always   closer than be imagine, see ya!

Answer (score 2):

With JSON responses, you should not need to manually parse them into JavaScript objects with `jQuery.parseJSON()`.

You can tell jQuery which data type to expect by specifying the `dataType` parameter to `jQuery.post()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).

For example,

```
jQuery.post(
    "file.php",
    function (data) { /* data is a JS object already-parsed */ },
    "json"  // <-- tell jQuery that we expect a JSON response
);
```

You should really be sending along a `Content-Type` header from your PHP script, telling jQuery (and everything else accessing the script) that the response is JSON with the `application/json` content type.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file , you should also set
header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Then may be you would like to mark the answer with some rewards :)